# ¿Por qué no se añade el panel que quiero?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Si hago directamente un this.add a cualquier panel si que me lo añade, pero al hacerlo de esta manera con un controlador, no.

Esta es mi ventana

```
public class Vista extends JFrame{
private JMenuBar barraMenu=new JMenuBar();
private JMenu menu=new JMenu("Opciones");
private JMenuItem reservas=new JMenuItem("Reservas");
private JMenuItem contabilidad=new JMenuItem("Contabilidad");
private JMenuItem salir=new JMenuItem("Salir");
private Controlador controlador;
private Reservas panelReservas=new Reservas();
private Contabilidad panelContabilidad=new Contabilidad();

public Vista(Controlador controlador){
    super("Reservas Hotel");
    this.controlador=controlador;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setSize(600,500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setJMenuBar(barraMenu);
    this.crearMenu();
    this.anadirEscuchadores();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void crearMenu() {
    menu.add(reservas);
    menu.add(contabilidad);
    menu.add(salir);
    barraMenu.add(menu);
}

private void anadirEscuchadores() {
    reservas.addActionListener(controlador);
    contabilidad.addActionListener(controlador);
    salir.addActionListener(controlador);
}

public void cambiarAReservas() {
    this.remove(panelContabilidad);
    this.add(panelReservas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void cambiarAContabilidad() {
    this.remove(panelReservas);
    this.add(panelContabilidad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

}

Este es mi controlador

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener{
private Vista vista;
private GestorBD modelo;

public Controlador(){
    vista=new Vista(this);
    modelo=new GestorBD();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    switch(evento.getActionCommand()){
        case "Reservas":
            vista.cambiarAReservas();
            break;
        case "Contabilidad":
            vista.cambiarAContabilidad();
            break;
        case "Salir":
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Al hacer click en Reservaa / Contabilidad no cambia el panel, ¿Es ese el problema?

Comment: Exacto, y sin embargo, si se ejecutan los metodos correspondientes

Comment: Hay un metodo que se llama setBounds. Por lo que recuerdo cuando trabajaba con swing, era necesario para hacer visible algunos elementos. ¿Probaste usarlo?

Comment: Si, pero la cosa es que estoy usando un BorderLayout por tanto no necesitaria posicionarlo. Como digo al principio, si lo añado directamente, sin usar controlador, si que funciona perfectamente

Comment: ¿Haz intentado hacer un `vista.repaint()` antes del `break`?

Comment: Si, y tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, faltaba poner .pack en los metodos que añaden los paneles.

```
public void cambiarAReservas() {
    this.remove(panelContabilidad);
    this.add(panelReservas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
}

public void cambiarAContabilidad() {
    this.remove(panelReservas);
    this.add(panelContabilidad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
}
```